# Check folder to be sure contents are downloaded completely using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a PowerShell solution. We have one server where some software downloads some folders into a folder called 'Receive.' These inner folders may contain 1 or more files. I have a script which monitors the Receive folder and moves all subfolders, including their data, from that server to another location. I have scheduled my script to do this every 10 minutes. However I have observed that, after moving the data, often either some of the folders' files are corrupted or some files are missing.

Is there any way we can check if data is getting copied into the remote folder and the script can ignore that one for the next occurrence?

Comment: You could get all files using into a array, wait 10-20 seconds and then get the files again in a separate list. Compare file names and sizes to see if any changed, if there are changes exclude those files.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the directory "Receive" is at "."

Assume that the timestamp of the receiving dirs/ files is NOT preserved.

I would check if the last file written to a directory is older than 20 min. This time is just intuitively taken by me as a half of your 10-min freq to allow that a single batch of files is completely received. Actually, it should be decided according to your data volume and frequency.

```
$recvDirs = (gci .\Receive)
$ageInSec = 1200
$refTime = get-date
foreach ($dir in $recvDirs) {

    $dir | add-member childLastWriteTime $dir.LastWriteTime
    foreach ($child in (gci $dir.fullname)) {

        # since $dir.lastwritetime is always = $child.lastwritetime
        foreach ($grandChild in (gci $child.fullname -recurse)) {

            if ($grandChild.lastWriteTime -gt $dir.childLastWriteTime) {

                $dir.childLastWriteTime = $grandChild.lastWriteTime
            }
        }
    }

    write-host $dir ": " $dir.childLastWriteTime
    if (($refTime - $dir.childLastWriteTime).TotalSeconds -gt $ageInSec) {

        write-host "moving " $dir "..."
        # do your move
    }
}
```

For a safer approach, if you can have the control on the receiving data, you should have an End-Of-Transmission signal/ file or a checksum file/ info to verify the completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Get-FileHash` to make sure the copy matches the original. It gives you an error if the file is missing and indicates whether the file downloaded completely and uncorrupted if it generates the same hash from the original file and copied file. The default hash algorithm is SHA256. As an alternative, look into `robocopy.exe` if you have it available.

Sample idea for using `Get-FileHash`:

```
$source = "\\server\path-to-files\"
$destination = "\\server2\destination-of-files\"
$files = Get-Childitem $source -File
$time = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss").ToString()
$loglocation = "C:\logs\"+"$time"+".txt"
$files | foreach {
                  $copiedfile = "$destination"+"$_"
                  $originalhash = (get-filehash $_.FullName).Hash
                  $copyhash = (get-filehash $copiedfile).Hash
                  if ($originalhash -eq $copyhash){
                                                  "'$_','Passed'" >> $loglocation
                                                  }
                  else {
                       "'$_','Retried'" >> $loglocation
                      ##Put copy command here
                       }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, indeed, you are going to have these big problems where you are syncing incompletely-downloaded files and syncing incomplete file lists. If you were on Linux you could use `incron` and look for the `IN_FILE_CLOSE` event that tells you that a file has been closed for writing, and trigger synchronization based on that, but it might still not help your subfolder-architecture approach.

The best approach would be to modify the software which dumps stuff into this folder. However, there are a lot of circumstances where you might not be able to do that.

The *next* best approach involves looking at the last-modified-time and only moving things which were last-modified a while ago, perhaps a day or so, maybe less.

If you really need to send them to a remote server, then I would recommend *separation of concerns* for these two issues: first, some daemon moves the folder F from `.\Receive\` to `.\Archiving\`, signifying completeness of upload, then another daemon working at a staggered time might try to send stuff from `.\Archiving\` to the remote server, doing the actual remote backup. A good script would try to send it and then move the folder to `.\Verify-Archival\` where another script would check "was this successfully uploaded, do the file lengths match, does a cryptographic hash or CRC match?" before deleting the local copy: if the hash doesn't match, instead of deleting, you just move to `.\Archiving\` and let the other daemon try again.

You can also separate concerns between *moving a file* (from `.\Receive\` to `.\Archiving\`) and *deleting the folders* if you need to free the space in `.\Receive\` quickly. Creating the new folder under `.\Archiving\` if it does not exist will be very fast, moving the file will be atomic, and once the file is gone we can presumably leave the subfolders in place for a day "just in case someone's not done uploading." Then you delete all subfolders which have remained empty for a day, cleaning those up too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the files are not corrupted because there is an error during you copying it (You can calculate hash as Booga Roo said to check that), but because you are copying files that are not completely downloaded in the first place. You would get similar error if you would open these files in their original location (='Receive' folder).

It might be hard to verify this, because the files can be fully downloaded in the original location when you notice it's corrupted in the copy location.

I would try to open each file for 'write' before copying it. If the file is still being downloaded then there is a write-lock on the file in the file system, so you won't be able to open it for 'write'.

If you can open it for 'write' you close it and copy it, if you can't you skip it and try it again next run.